# Saving button state when Orientation is changing in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm writing an app in Android Studio. 
The activity looks the following way:

[image]

The code:

```
class Kadr13Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kadr13)
}

var flag = false

fun nextClick(view: View) {
    if (flag) COUNT ++

    val intentKadr14 = Intent(this, Kadr14Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentKadr14)
    this.finish()

}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val intentKadr12 = Intent(this, Kadr12Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentKadr12)
    this.finish()
}

fun btn1Click(view: View){
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1_chosen)
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2)
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3)
    flag = false
}

fun btn2Click(view: View){
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2_chosen)
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1)
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3)
    flag = true
}

fun btn3Click(view: View){
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3_chosen)
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1)
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2)
    flag = false
}
}
```

So, when the user presses the button the picture is changed.

However, when the orientation of the screen is changed the button is "deselected". How do I save button state? Thank you for any possible help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Android lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras) and the linked part about saving and restoring instance state.

What you can do specifically is getting your Button state when inside onSaveInstanceState (for example put a boolean into the bundle with a name like BUTTON_SELECTED) and then in onCreate(which is called after rotating) getting that value from the bundle that is passed to you and then setting the button state as you want to